# How to install NPM dependencies behind proxy even after I have made recommended changes in NPM CONFIG following other SO answers?

Tags: node.js, npm, userfrosting

I am using:

- 64 bit Windows 10 platform
- composer 1.10.10 (globally installed)
- node ~12.14
- NPM ~6.13
- XAMPP with PHP 7.2.33

I am working with a project that will be using the PHP package named *"User Frosting v4.4.4"*

From the command line of this package I have to run the following command

```
PHP bakery build-assets
```

whereby NPM dependencies should be installed.

I am behind a proxy, so I tried by making the required changes with `npm config` (as per other answers). However, NPM dependency install hangs after an indefinitely long time, then it gives me a *"Meta-Data-Fetch"* error.

@gulp and NPM dependency install fails behind my proxy which is not set hinder NPM but it says network settings are not correct.

So as you will understand that for my package to work this command `PHP bakery build-assets` is required to execute by installing NPM dependencies and do its job successfully gets aborted.